# `caption =` argument not working in kable() R

Tags: r, latex, kable, kableextra

I'm having trouble exporting a kable table with LaTex using save_kable() function after I add the `caption =`  argument in kable() function.

I thought it was because I recently updated my R version, RStudio version, TeX version, and everything that could cause errors, but then I switch to R Servers (R 4.3.2 currently), which I never touched upon before. I got the same error message that says "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." If I delete the `caption =`, I was able to export the table in LaTex. Here is a minimum example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(magick)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
dt %>%
  kbl("latex",caption = "Recreating booktabs style table") %>%
  save_kable(file = "a.png")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I do get the same error when including the `caption` argument in `kable()`.
There are alternatives to this, that don’t require Latex.
You could use `gt::gt()` to create a nice table and then save
it with `gtsave()`.

```r
library(gt)
table <-
  mtcars[1:5, 1:6] |>
  gt() |>
  tab_header("Recreating booktabs style table")

table
```

[image]

```r
# Save as png:
gtsave(table, "a.png")
```